# Spring Data Rest cannot do Integration test?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have tried to use both MockMVC and TestRestTemplate. In both cases, the response back is 404 but the API endpoints work outside of integration test (when I run the spring app on its own).

Does anyone have a working sample app that has a working integration test for a **generated controller** using Spring Data Rest?

I was also able to write regular integration tests against my own controllers (Non SDR types)

Test code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testApi() {
        String settings = testRestTemplate
                .getForObject("/api/v1/orders", String.class);
        System.out.println(settings);
    }

}
```

Repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = OrderSummaryProjection.class)
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {}
```

---

**Ok I found out the issue** but I dont know what the answer should be:

I set spring.data.rest.basePath in application.properties.

But I don't think that file is read when you run the integration tests. How do I fix that?

Comment: Your code snippet will help in answering the question

Comment: @Smile found the issue, but dont have the answer see edit

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't test Spring Data Rest endpoints, but if I were to do it, I would test interfaces using classical Integration test approach:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DummyIT {

    @Autowired
    private SettingsRepository settingsRepository;

    @Test
    public void testApi() {
        List<Settings> settings = settingsRepository.findAll();
        assertNotNull(settings);
    }

}
```

I also tested end-to-end test and it also works, it just returns ugly {"_embedded" : {"settings" : [ { ... } ] }, ... } so it's doable, but it's not pretty:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class DummyTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testApi() {
        String settings = testRestTemplate
                .getForObject("/api/settings", String.class);
        System.out.println(settings);
    }

}
```

Comment: I found the issue, but dont have the answer see edit